# Create biggest x by y image from upload, keeping proportions and centered

Tags: php, image, file-upload, gd

I'm trying to create a script with GD library that will take an uploaded image of any size and create the biggest x by y thumb of it, keeping it's proportions, and if the image is too small, it get's the biggest x/y ratio of it and enlarges it, keeping it centered.

I'm not concerned about pixelating the image.

Take the following examples

[image]

I know it's doable but I get stuck on calculating the x/y coordinates

Here's where I'm at so far.  I'm trying to create 3 thumbs with defined sizes

```
<?php

    $sizes = array(
        array(
            'width' => 640,
            'height' => 360
        ),
        array(
            'width' => 222,
            'height' => 166
        ),
        array(
            'width' => 140,
            'height' => 105
        )
    );

    if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {

        $file = $_FILES['image'];

        foreach($sizes as $size) {

            if (strpos($file['type'], 'jpeg') !== false || strpos($file['type'], 'jpg') !== false) {

                $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
            }
            else if (strpos($file['type'], 'png') !== false) {

                $resource = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
            }
            else if (strpos($file['type'], 'gif') !== false) {

                $resource = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
            }
            else {

                echo "bad file type " . $file['type'];
                exit;
            }

            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);

            $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor($size['width'], $size['height']);

            /*

            need to do some calculations here

            */

            imagecopyresampled($tmpImage, $resource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size['width'], $size['height']);

            ob_start();
            imagepng($tmpImage);
            $image = ob_get_clean();

            echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';

            imagedestroy($tmpImage);
        }

        var_dump($file, $width, $height);
    }

    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Okay. So each uploaded image will create three thumbs, all of which are wider than tall, right? And in all cases you want the thumbnail to  keep the aspect ratio, right? So now I am trying to understand the blue and red.. If the supplied image is too wide, you want to resize the height of the original to fit the desired/thumbnail height and then crop off the sides? If the supplied image is too tall you want to resize the width to match the thumbnail/desired width and crop off the top and bottom. In both of these cases you want the image centered on the thumbnail? .. But what is the last case?

Comment: In the last case, grab the biggest proportionally correct (to the red) you can, centered, then expand it to meet the original dimensions of the red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your consideration:

```
<?php

$sizes = array(
    array(
        'width' => 640,
        'height' => 360
    ),
    array(
        'width' => 222, 
        'height' => 166
    ),
    array(
        'width' => 140,
        'height' => 105
    )
);

if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {

    $file = $_FILES['image'];

    foreach($sizes as $size) {

        if (strpos($file['type'], 'jpeg') !== false || strpos($file['type'], 'jpg') !== false) {

            $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
        }
        else if (strpos($file['type'], 'png') !== false) {

            $original_image = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
        }
        else if (strpos($file['type'], 'gif') !== false) {

            $original_image = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
        }
        else {

            echo "bad file type " . $file['type'];
            exit;
        }

        $thumbnail_image = imagecreatetruecolor($size['width'], $size['height']);

        $original_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        $original_width = $original_size[0];
        $original_height = $original_size[1];
        $adjusted_original_width = $original_size[0];
        $adjusted_original_height = $original_size[1];

        $fitting = false;
        $original_aspect_ratio = $original_width/$original_height; // larger is wider
        $ideal_thumbnail_aspect_ratio = $size['width']/$size['height']; // larger is wider
        if($original_aspect_ratio > $ideal_thumbnail_aspect_ratio) $fitting = 'wide'; // the original is wider than the ideal
        else if($original_aspect_ratio < $ideal_thumbnail_aspect_ratio) $fitting = 'tall'; // the original is taller than the ideal

        $src_x = 0;
        $src_y = 0;

        if($fitting=='wide') {
            $adjusted_original_width = $original_height * $size['width']/$size['height'];
            $src_x = ($original_width-$adjusted_original_width)/2;
        }
        else {
            $adjusted_original_height = $original_width * $size['height']/$size['width'];
            $src_y = ($original_height-$adjusted_original_height)/2;
        }

        $thumbnail_image = imagecreatetruecolor($size['width'], $size['height']);

        imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_image, $original_image, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $size['width'], $size['height'], $adjusted_original_width, $adjusted_original_height);

        ob_start();
        imagepng($thumbnail_image);
        $image = ob_get_clean();

        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';

        imagedestroy($thumbnail_image);
    }

    var_dump($file, $original_width, $original_height);
}

exit;
```